# Adding custom sort order to pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I made a many-to-many relationship between my User and my Worker model. If a User adds a worker to his account, the Worker model gets attached to the user. This works just fine. But now I want to add a costum sort order each user can modify according to his needs (basically clicking up and down buttons in a table to move his workers up and down in the list). So I added a sort_id to my pivot table. But I struggle with setting the sort_id. I have 2 questions:

I attach the Worker to the User like this: `$request->user()->workers()->attach($worker);` But how can I add the sort_id  to the pivot table?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying but isn't it just doing: `$request->user()->workers()->orderBy('column', 'DESC')` or `ASC` ? Provide some more code if you can.

Comment: No, my problem is, that I need to add the sort_id to the pivot table.

Comment: Or to be more precise: How do I determine the sort_id I need to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function workers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Worker')
                ->withPivot('sort_id')
                ->orderBy('pivot_sort_id','asc');
}
```

Then to edit the sort_id

```
$user->workers()->updateExistingPivot($workerId, ['sort_id'=>$newSortId]);
```

Comment: Thanks! The "updateExistingPivot" was the nice, small function I was looking for :)